# T_FILL_THIS_FORM_SHORT in spam assassin

Tags: spam-prevention, spamassassin

I am sending an email, and the spam filter always consider it as spam.
The most points are given to this validation:

T_FILL_THIS_FORM_SHORT=3

At spam assassin website the description says this:
FILL_THIS_FORM  - Fill in a form with personal information.

I couldn't find anything that gives a more detailed explanation about this validation, and how to prevent it.

Does anyone have any hint?

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because email deliverability questions are not programming questions. See also https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/302903/off-topic-my-email-isnt-spam

Comment: Having this heuristic rule with a 3.0 score is probably a local tweak. Maybe talk to the administrator of this SpamAssassin installation.